# how can i reference 'this' from within my for loop and function?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have a for loop like below:

```
function activate () {
...some code
..here we know what 'this' is
  if( i > 0...) {               
    function setNodeInvisible(ode) {
        for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
            if (node.children[i].isMesh) {
                this._view.setVisibility(node, false, false);
            }
        }
    }
   }
}
```

but it doesnt know what this is.

outside of this for loop my 'this' is equal to viewport. and i use it fine.

Also here is doesnt know what 'this' is:

```
function iterateP (parent) {
    this._view.setVisibility(parent, true, false);
}
```

hoew can i get this is these places?

Comment: use a variable such as `var self = this ` outside the loop and use `self` inside your forLoop

Comment: That's not possible. The value of `this` doesn't changed inside a loop body. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this Some basic JS knowledge will help you answer your question

Comment: Can you please post the entire code? 'this' is completely dependent on WHERE you call it. In other words, where do you call iterateP()?? without the entire code we cant tell you what 'this' points to.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: It's still not a complete example. You are not showing how `activate` or `setNodeInvisibility` is called. However, the duplicate should help.

Answer (score 0):

the value of `this` is depends on the caller function context. If you want to specify the value of `this`, you can use `apply()` and `call()` to call the function.

You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to know more about it.

Comment: Harlan, apply() and call() arent the only ways to specify the value of 'this' It ultimately depends on where he called it and how he will want to call it.

Comment: please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a design problem, but not enough info to help with that. In the meantime, you can use `.call()` to use the current `this` value in the `setVisibility` call.

```
this._view.setVisibility.call(this, node, false, false);
```

The nature of your original call was that `this` was implicitly set to the `_view` object because of your call to `setVisibility` from that object. In other words, the object to the left of the method becomes the value of `this`.

Using `.call` lets you manually set the value of `this` in the function being called to whatever value you want. In this case, we used the current `this` value by passing it as the first argument.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @SarahFar: Sorry, but you really need to take the time to produce a small demo that fully illustrates the issue. All you're showing now is a function inside an `if` statement, which doesn't tell us much, and you're pretty vague in the description.